# Перенос данных с django cms 2.4 на django cms 3.1.2

Tags: база-данных, django, django-cms

Встала проблема переноса базы с cms 2.4 на 3.1.2. В частности перенести страницы.
Структура таблицы в cms 2.4:

```
CREATE TABLE "cms_page" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "created_by" varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    "changed_by" varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    "parent_id" integer,
    "creation_date" datetime NOT NULL,
    "changed_date" datetime NOT NULL,
    "publication_date" datetime,
    "publication_end_date" datetime,
    "in_navigation" bool NOT NULL,
    "soft_root" bool NOT NULL,
    "reverse_id" varchar(40),
    "navigation_extenders" varchar(80),
    "published" bool NOT NULL,
    "template" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "site_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "django_site" ("id"),
    "login_required" bool NOT NULL,
    "limit_visibility_in_menu" smallint,
    "level" integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    "lft" integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    "rght" integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    "tree_id" integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    "publisher_is_draft" bool NOT NULL,
    "publisher_public_id" integer UNIQUE,
    "publisher_state" smallint NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_410d0aac" ON "cms_page" ("parent_id");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_ecf7107f" ON "cms_page" ("publication_date");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_fef6ef40" ON "cms_page" ("publication_end_date");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_a49c2a2e" ON "cms_page" ("in_navigation");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_5566f6cf" ON "cms_page" ("soft_root");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_47dd39d3" ON "cms_page" ("reverse_id");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_5d1be695" ON "cms_page" ("navigation_extenders");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_99732b5c" ON "cms_page" ("site_id");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_83b09d4f" ON "cms_page" ("limit_visibility_in_menu");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_b8f3f94a" ON "cms_page" ("level");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_f777e2bb" ON "cms_page" ("lft");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_76886718" ON "cms_page" ("rght");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_f391089a" ON "cms_page" ("tree_id");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_8f14a007" ON "cms_page" ("publisher_is_draft");
CREATE INDEX "cms_page_0a4ff810" ON "cms_page" ("publisher_state");
```

Структура таблицы в cms 3.1.2:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms_page` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `changed_by` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `changed_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `publication_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `publication_end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_navigation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `soft_root` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `reverse_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `navigation_extenders` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `template` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `login_required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `limit_visibility_in_menu` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_home` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `application_urls` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `application_namespace` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher_is_draft` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `languages` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `xframe_options` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher_public_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `depth` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `numchild` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cms_page_path_518270318703c18f_uniq` (`path`),
  UNIQUE KEY `publisher_public_id` (`publisher_public_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cms_page_reverse_id_a864144bd3516c9_uniq` (`reverse_id`,`site_id`,`publisher_is_draft`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cms_page_publisher_is_draft_7597e61e0082d3aa_uniq` (`publisher_is_draft`,`site_id`,`application_namespace`),
  KEY `cms_page_93b83098` (`publication_date`),
  KEY `cms_page_2247c5f0` (`publication_end_date`),
  KEY `cms_page_db3eb53f` (`in_navigation`),
  KEY `cms_page_1d85575d` (`soft_root`),
  KEY `cms_page_3d9ef52f` (`reverse_id`),
  KEY `cms_page_7b8acfa6` (`navigation_extenders`),
  KEY `cms_page_cb540373` (`limit_visibility_in_menu`),
  KEY `cms_page_4fa1c803` (`is_home`),
  KEY `cms_page_e721871e` (`application_urls`),
  KEY `cms_page_b7700099` (`publisher_is_draft`),
  KEY `cms_page_6be37982` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `cms_page_9365d6e7` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Добавляю страницу следующим SQL запросом:

```
INSERT INTO 
 `cms_page`(`id`,`created_by`,`changed_by`,`parent_id`,`creation_date`,`changed_date`,`publication_date`,`publication_end_date`,`in_navigation`,`soft_root`,`reverse_id`,`navigation_extenders`,`template`,`site_id`,`login_required`,`limit_visibility_in_menu`,`publisher_is_draft`,`publisher_public_id`,`is_home`,`application_urls`,`application_namespace`,`languages`,`revision_id`,`xframe_options`,`depth`,`numchild`,`path`) 

VALUES
(4,'admin','admin',117,'2013-04-23 14:15:55','2015-03-18 14:58:04.681781','2013-04-23 14:34:14',NULL,1,0,NULL,NULL,'article.html',1,0,NULL,1,10, 0,NULL,NULL,'ru',0,0,1,'',1);
```

При открытии http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/cms/page/ получаю следующею ошибку:

> AttributeError at /admin/cms/page/
>   'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title_cache'

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно перенести данные?

Answer (score 2):

Вы пробовали выполнить

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py migrate
```

после установки 3 версии cms?

Эти две команды являются стандартными действиями при обновлении django приложений. 
В документации по переходу с django cms с 2.4.* на 3 версию он указаны.
В случае если при обновлении с 2.4 на 3.1.2 эти команды не помогают. Стоит обновляться в два этапа. Сначала с 2.4 на 3.0, затем с 3.0 на 3.1.
Вот ссылка на официалное руководство: https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.0.html#upgrading-from-2-4.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?